# Is php's own hash framework better than phpass

Tags: php, hash

Until now, and I haven't used it much, I've been using the hasher found over at [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass).  Then I read another post, "[forget password page, creating a generated password to email to the user.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283653/forget-password-page-creating-a-generated-password-to-email-to-the-user)", here at stackoverflow written by [nageeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694286/nageeb).

Excerpt from his post:

> Here's a step-by-step method that I use:
>
> User creates password (via a registration form)
>   A function creates a random salt and then encrypts the password, in this case, using SHA256 algorithm and using a randomly created salt.
>
> **$password_salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));**
>
> **$password_hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $password);**
>
> Save the $password_hash and the $password_salt to the users table. These will be used later to authenticate the user when they attempt to login in the future.
>
> When the user logs in, check the username/email/login and if found, grab the hash and salt from the users table and compare the password hash from the db to the hash returned from performing the same function on what they entered as their password.
>
> **$salt = $user_record['password_salt'];**
>
> **$entered_hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $entered_password);**

Here it looks like php have native functions for all hashing needs.  This make me think it must be the better one.  Should I stop using phpass and start using the php hash framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: **no**, don't stop using phpass if you're already using it.

If there is no other reason for not using it as "it's not built into PHP" then you should stick with phpass, because it does a little bit more than just "hash" the password:

- It tries to use blowfish for hashing because it's [more expensive to compute](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) than `sha*` and therefore harder to crack with brute force
- If it has to fall back to `md5()` it calls it many times to "emulate" expensiveness.

You could do that with PHP's hashing mechanism but that would be like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanx.  I read the link you mentioned and it basically says it all - phpass uses blowfish and that's the way to go for passwords.