# Change Password script in PHP and MD5 hashing

Tags: php, mysql, md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [forget password page, creating a generated password to email to the user.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283653/forget-password-page-creating-a-generated-password-to-email-to-the-user)

I am trying to create a change password page. The code below should check to make sure the user is in the database, confirm there current password and allow them to change their password. It validates their new password correctly checking to make sure they are the same and a certain length, but it does not return an error message if the user name is not in the database and it says that the current password to a user that is in the database is wrong. I think it is not matching the hash passwords correctly but I am not sure. Can anyone help me fix these problems. Thanks.

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Change Password Confrim</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
      $db_server = "server";
       $db_username = "name";
       $db_password = "pass";

       $con = mysql_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_password);if (!$con)
                {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

               $database = "User";  

              $er = mysql_select_db($db_username);
        if (!$er) 
        {
         print ("Error - Could not select the database");
         exit;
        }        



//////////Collect the form data ////////////////////
$username =$_P0ST['username'];
$cur_password=$_POST['cur_password'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$password2=$_POST['password2'];
/////////////////////////



$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($password2);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username); 
$cur_password = mysql_real_escape_string($cur_password); 
//Setting flags for checking
$status = "OK";
$msg="";

//Checking to see if password is at least 3 char max 8 
if ( strlen($password) < 3 or strlen($password) > 15 )
{
    $msg=$msg."Password must be more than 3 char legth and maximum 15 char lenght<br/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";
}                   

//Checking to see if both passwords match 
if ( $password <> $password2 )
{
    $msg=$msg."Both passwords are not matching<br/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";
}                   

     $CorrectUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE username ='$username' AND password = MD5('$cur_password')");
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($CorrectUser);
      if ($row['username'] == $username) 
          {
          $status = "OK"; 
          }
       else {
                print("Your username is not in the database. Please check that you enter the correct username and try again."); 
                $status = "NOTOK";
            }

        if ($row['cur_password'] == MD5('$cur_password')) 
            {
                $status = "OK"; 
            }
         else
             {
                print("You entered the wrong current passowrd"); 
                $status = "NOTOK"; 
             }


if($status<>"OK"){ 
echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' color=red>$msg</font><br><center><input type='button' value='Retry' onClick='history.go(-1)'></center>";
}
else
{ // if all validations are passed.
    if(mysql_query("UPDATE User SET password = MD5('$password') WHERE username ='$username'"))
    {
        echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' ><center>Thanks <br> Your password changed successfully.</font></center>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' color=red><center>Sorry <br> Failed to change password.</font></center>";
    }

}

?>
<center>
<br><br><a href='Settings.html'>Settings Page</a></center> 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try comparing escaped and non-escaped hashes since that might be the problem.

Comment: Please do not repost questions, especially when you have received useful feedback on the first one

Comment: The following line:
`mysql_select_db($db_username);` should cause a problem in case the database name is not the same as the username

Comment: Please use SHA256 and salts when hashing passwords.  See also [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `AND password = MD5('$cur_password')` from your SQL query. That way you will find the user whether or not the password is correct. Your in-PHP test that `$row['cur_password'] == MD5('$cur_password')` suffices; you don't need to put it in your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP line:

```
if ($row['cur_password'] == MD5('$cur_password'))
```

Should probably be

```
if ($row['cur_password'] == MD5($cur_password))
```

However it looks like your already checking the password in the database.

Additionally, you set $status = 'NOTOK' if the password and password2 don't match, but ignore that result.   ie:  if you has mismatched password & password2, but a matching user/password, it will still update.

And unless your required to use unsalted MD5, it may be wise to add a salt.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this line is not OK

```
$CorrectUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE username ='$username' AND password = MD5('$cur_password')");
```

Look at it this way.. :

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE username ='BOB' AND password = 32RE5446DDGDDDYHBD" <-- THE QUOTES ARE MISSING HERE
```

Try it like this :

```
$CorrectUser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE username ='".$username."' AND password = '".MD5($cur_password)."'");
```

It is a good practice to "isolate" your variables, it avoids a lot of errors.

Comment: MySQL (and virtually every DB for that matter) has an MD5 function, so technically the query was still valid. Secondly, your second code block doesn't make any sense. You **don't need** to quote the result of a call to the database's MD5 function.